# How to detect failed DB change with TypeORM relationQueryBuilder remove relation

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

The tech Stack used is - TypeORM with NestJs.
I am making the below query to remove a relation that is part of a ManyToMany relationship. The happy path works fine - it's the detecting when the update failed that I have an issue.
Ideally, I would like to achieve this without additional DB calls (highly inefficient)
The return value is undefined and there is no exception thrown in the try/catch block.

Profile entity

```
@ManyToMany((_type) => Relationship, (relationship) =>       
 relationship.users)
@JoinTable({
 name: 'user_relationship_map',
 joinColumn: { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
 inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'relationshipId' },
})
relationships: Relationship[];
```

Relationship Entity

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.relationships)
users: User[];
```

Remove relationship (based on  TypeORM docs)

```
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user');
try {
  const result = await query
    .relation(relationshipType) 
    .of(userId)
    .remove(relationshipId);

  this.logger.log(`after remove query:  ${result}`);
} catch (err) {
  this.logger.warn(err.message);
  return { status: MessageStatus.ERROR, message: err.message };
}
```

Logger shows "after remove query: undefined"

How do I detect that the update did not occur so this can be reported back to UI?

Many thanks

Comment: `of(...)` property of RelationQueryBuilder is supposed to be an entity, not a column: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a868078f8f4f63cc8d81a63e098d639ed12c6608/src/query-builder/RelationQueryBuilder.ts#L31. Futhermore, `remove(...)` method is void.

Comment: @Azerpas.  The documentation states that you can pass in either an object or the id. This works fine if I pass the correct ID.  The good path works fine. The issue is with the error path. If I pass an incorrect id it fails to make the update but does not indicate the update failed. I am looking to see how I can identify that the update failed.